# Writing Regex that selects a VBScript Class and it's Name

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am writing a regex that selects a VBScript class and it's name. At the moment here is how it look.

**Regex:**

```
Class\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

[image]

**Live Code Demo:** http://regexr.com/3bco8

It is fine, but I want a modification so that it only selects the "`Class Person`" and not select the word `class` at the end of the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `*` quantifiers should be replaced with `+` (**one** or more of). Using the .Multiline flag, anchoring at start, and capturing the class name may be a good idea. Whether you want to allow leading whitespace before `Class` is up to you:

```
Option Explicit

Dim s : s = Join(Array( _
    "' Class ForgetIt" _
  , "whatever" _
  , " Class FindIt" _
  , "whatever" _
  , "End Class ' FindIt" _
  , "s = ""Class NotMe""" _
  , "CLASS MeToo" _
  , "End Class" _
), vbCrLf)
Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global = True
r.IgnoreCase = True
r.Multiline = True
r.Pattern = "^\s*Class\s+(\w+)+"
Dim m
For Each m In r.Execute(s)
    WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 31398009.vbs
FindIt
MeToo
```